# send email with dynamically created url c#

Tags: c#, rest, http, windows-services

**What I want to accomplish:**

I have a Windows Service that creates an email based on some DB data. (Not a problem)

I want the service to be able to create a one time use link, along the lines of `http://thisserver:80/someGuid/whicheverURL`
and listen on this Url until someone presses the link (I guess it could be some sort of rest 'post' thing)

**What I need:**

- What are my options for creating a runtime url and a listener for this url using SelfHosted WebApi
- Some guidance on how to do this (doesn't have to be specific
  examples.
- To see which "guid" has been accessed through the Get

**Bear in mind**

I do not need to show any data, just check if the user actually clicks the link and then run some internal process

as always, thanks in advance :)

**The solution**
what I've found to be a suitable solution -> based on the marked answer & based on http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

I'm selfhosting the "site" in a WindowsService (No IIS)

Main:

```
var baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/");
        var guidList = new string[]{
           "89ac3d67-81fc-4294-bacc-72a97469cc95",
           "99ac3d67-81fc-4294-bacc-72a97469cc95",
           "09ac3d67-81fc-4294-bacc-72a97469cc95",
        };
        foreach (var guid in guidList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(guid);
            var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress + guid);

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("default", "{controller}/{id}", new { controller = new JobController(), id = RouteParameter.Optional });
            var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Server is opened");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

The Controller

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var request = ControllerContext.RequestContext.Url.Request.RequestUri;
        Uri UrlGuid = request.RequestUri;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has been accessed", UrlGuid.Segments[1]);
        return new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new StringContent("Some Content Here")
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Web API or MVC:

- I would create a row in a table with a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` (C# GUID) that will be used to identify the record.
- The Url could simply be:  `http://servername:80/controller?id=<the guid>`  However with custom routings you could create the URI the way you originally wanted with the GUID in the URI
- Make the controller receive the guid key and mark the record as consumed.

Example of controller in MVC 5.0

```
public class TestController: Controller
{

   public ActionResult ProcessResponse(Guid id)
   {
        //
        //lookup & process the record using the id...
        //
        return View("ThankYou");  // <-- will display the "ThankYou.cshtml" view
   }
}
```

Comment: I would also recommend that the url is sent via https, rather than http, in order to prevent security issues, as it will most probably be clicked from within the email. Also, if the url is unique for each user, maybe there should also be some indication to who the Guid belongs in the table record.

Comment: So you're talking about selfhosted webAPI - correct? :)

Comment: How would i make the controller receive the guid key? (Ive never used MVC) - I am created a P.O.C using selfhosted aspnet webAPI

Comment: Marking as answer as it led me in the right direction, atleast for what i've found to be a valid solution